# Não estou conseguindo modificar o valor da classe LivroFisico que é um Livro

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, groovy

Já fiz de tudo e nada do valor ser modificado... Como faz?
Utilizei herança no livro físico, a classe está assim:

```
class Livrofisico extends Livro{

    public Livrofisico (Autor autor){
        super(autor)
    }

    public double getTaxaImpressao(){
        return this.getValor() + 5.0
    }
}
```

Classe livro:

```
package crud

class Livro {

    String nome
    String descricao
    double valor
    String isbn
    Autor autor


    void mostrarDetalhes() {
        println "mostrando detalhes do livro: "
        println "Nome: " + nome
        println "Descrição: " + descricao
        println "ISBN " + isbn
        println "Valor: "+ valor
        autor.mostrarDetalhes()
        println "-----------------------------"
    }
        public Livro(Autor autor) {
        this()
        this.autor = autor
        }

        public Livro(){
            this.isbn = "0000-0000000-000000-000000-00"
            this.nome = ""
        }
}
```

```
package crud

class Start {
    static main(args) {
        Autor autor = new Autor()
        autor.nome = "Aline Gonzaga"
        autor.email ='65767@yahoo.com.br'
        autor.cpf =' 8695649864496'

        Livro livro = new Livro(autor)
        livro.nome='Java: desvendando o segredo para ser mestre em Java'
        livro.descricao= 'Trata de um guia para aperfeiçoar em java'
        livro.valor =65.65
        //livro.isbn= "8975849-54-5665-34-3-324-656-32-34-123"
        //livro.autor = autor

        Autor autor2 = new Autor()
        autor2.nome = "Gonzaga"

        Livrofisico fisico = new Livrofisico(autor2)
        fisico.nome =" javaScript"
        fisico.valor =39.99
        fisico.getTaxaImpressao()
        fisico.mostrarDetalhes()


        livro.mostrarDetalhes()

        Ebook ebook = new Ebook()

        Autor outroAutor = new Autor()
        outroAutor.cpf ='754.548.545-34'
        outroAutor.email='li@email.com'
        outroAutor.nome='Jesus Cristo'

        Livro outroLivro = new Livro(outroAutor)
        outroLivro.descricao =' Como fazer?'
        outroLivro.isbn = ' 8754868596845986946'
    //  outroLivro.nome =''
        outroLivro.valor = 467.99
    //  outroLivro.autor = outroAutor
        outroLivro.mostrarDetalhes()

    }
}
```

Comment: Renan eu não estou conseguindo o valor do livro físico. Eu não estou conseguindo alterar já que ele tem uma taxa de impressão, o ebook não precisa da taxa. Eu quero incluir o valor da taxa no livro impresso... : /

Comment: Isso é groovy, não esquenta.

Comment: **Me ajuda?** Sim?

Comment: @AlineGonz Explique melhor o que está acontencendo de errado, qual linha está causando problemas, qual é o erro exibido etc.

Comment: O valor que tem no livro ele precisa ser somado com o que tem no getTaxaImpressao(){} da classe LivroFisico, mas não é o que está ocorrendo...

Comment: Não dá erro no console, o problema é que ele não soma...

Comment: Se puder edita a pergunta com a saída obtida e a saída desejada. Vai ajudar a entender seu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alguns detalhes iniciais que não causam grandes problemas, mas vai se acostumando fazer certo:

- Procure indentar e espaçar corretamente, facilita entender o que está acontecendo
- Evite misturar métodos que apresentam dados com os que manipulam o objeto. Entendo que este é só um exemplo, mas é comum as pessoas aprenderem assim e depois continuam fazendo igual o resto da vida.
- Eu não conheço Groovy, mas tem certeza que precisa chamar `this()` dentro do [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) desta forma? Esta construção me parece estranha.
- Está guardando um valor monetário em `double` que [dá erros de cálculo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101), ninguém vai perder dinheiro em um exemplo para aprender, mas se continuar fazendo isto vai causar prejuízos.
- Fico pensando se `Livro` não deveria ser uma classe abstrata e até mesmo chamar `LivroAbstract` (algumas pessoas usam esta convenção). Me parece estranho poder criar um livro e um livro físico. Se mudar isto, a classe concreta pode se chamar apenas `Livro`, o que faria mais sentido.

Fora isto não tive nenhum problema, como pode ser [visto no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iK9zAs). Tive que fazer adaptações porque o código não era compilável no estado que estava. E dei uma organizada no estilo. Se adicionar informações, eu tento melhorar a resposta.

[Também coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Model.groovy).

Comment: Eu preciso do livro físico porque tem a versão impressa e a versão de livro ebook. O que ocorre é que o livro físico é cobrado uma taxa de impressão o que não ocorre cm o livro ebook que não possui esse valor de impressão. Ficou claro?

Comment: qual a melhor forma de guardar dinheiro?

Comment: Isto eu entendi. Mas eu falei de outra coisa. Não sei se Groovy tem algo diferente, Java usa `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Mas não tem uma solução para mim? :(

Comment: Hum, só vou comentar porque eu coloquei o **this()** dentro do construtor. Se a classe tivesse construtor sem argumentos  o valor de **ISBN** só seria inicializado se o construtor recebesse um autor. Então para resolver isso eu coloquei o this para encandear a chamada para o outro construtor.

Comment: Como eu não vi problema, não vejo solução.Está tudo funcionando. Esses construtores parecem todos errados. Mas posso estar errado. Por isso eu *linkei* uma outra pergunta sobre o assunto.

Comment: Irei ler sim. Está somando o valor aí da taxa de impressão??

Comment: Clica ali em cima e veja executando direitinho.

Comment: Clicar em cima?

Comment: http://ideone.com/oJqy8n

Comment: Resolvi o problema!!!!!!

Comment: Então conta qual é, porque eu mostrei que ele não existe no código postado.

Comment: [codigo](http://ideone.com/mlSef0)  Aqui está @bigown

Comment: Isto está conceitualmente errado. Tem um método que diz que vai pegar uma valor e dentro dele **modifica** outro valor. Isto está muito errado, induz a erro quem vai usar o método. Pode até não fazer diferença neste exemplo de aprendizado que não será usado de fato em algum lugar importante, mas treinar errado produzirá resultado errado. Ou seja, estava tudo certo, agora está errado. Se deseja mudar o valor, crie algo que mude o valor explicitamente. Embora essa lógica toda não faz sentido. Ou a impressão é isolada ou ela faz parte do preço. Você está codificando certo, mas estruturando errado

Comment: Isto já foge do escopo desta pergunta. Precisaria de outra para não bagunçar todo o conteúdo.

Comment: Não assim que funciona aqui. Somos um site de perguntas e respostas e não de consultoria individual.

Answer (score 1):

Se o valor não está sendo somado tenta isso:

`public double getTaxaImpressao(Livro livro){
        return livro.getValor() + 5.0;
    }
}`

Ou

`public double getTaxaImpressao(Livro livro){
        Double valor = livro.getValor();
        return valor + 5.0;
    }
}`

Se o valor não está sendo exibido tenta isso:

`Double valor = fisico.getTaxaImpressao();
 System.out.println(valor);`

Comment: Mas amigo, isso não está certo. : / Autor não tem valor, só o livro...